# Why does NULL assignment outside main function return an error

Tags: c, pointers

This piece of code return an error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int* a;
a = NULL;

int main(){
    printf("works");
    return 0;
}
```

whereas this one does not...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int* a= NULL;

int main(){

    printf("works");
    return 0;
}
```

What's the difference and why does this show the re-declaration error?
If I do the same thing inside main function it works. But not outside.

Comment: You can't have executable statements outside a function, only declarations and initializations.

Comment: You can't have generic statements outside of functions. The first one you show is a definition followed by an assignment, the second is a definition with initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a = NULL;` is a statement you can put only in the body of function

`int* a= NULL;` is the definition with initialization of the global variable *a*